# Spring MVC change DataSource

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC 4 application, and here is one of my JPAConfig, I have to configure two different datasources Here is the definition of the class and datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = MassaContratos.class, enableDefaultTransactions = false,
                        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory08",transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager08")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig08 {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource08() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/DB08");
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter08() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        adapter.setShowSql(false);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory08() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource08());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter08());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(MassaContrato.class.getPackage().getName());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager08() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory08());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

What I need to do and I  don't know how to do is... How to change this

```
dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/DB08");
```

To pick from other DB configs

For example:

```
dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/DB08-dev");
```

I need to change the data sources dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you will be able to do that, since that isn't what JNDI is trying to achieve.

JNDI defers configuration to the container. That way your JNDI name is the same, in whatever environment it runs. The container config. determines which database that JNDI name points to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple **pre-configured** data sources, [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) might help you.

Here is a good example: http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/